# Errors while trying to use System.Drawing in .Net Core Console Application

Tags: c#, .net-core, ubuntu-18.04, dllnotfoundexception

I am trying to create a Bitmap with [System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common) in a .Net Core Console Application running on Ubuntu 18.04, but as soon as I execute the code it will show me:

```
The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception.
   at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipCreateBitmapFromScan0(Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 stride, Int32 format, HandleRef scan0, IntPtr& bitmap)
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height, PixelFormat format)
   at MidnightBot.Modules.AdminCommands.CreatePollAsync(String Term1, String Term2, String Description) in /home/MidnightBot/Modules/AdminCommands.cs:line 125
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'libgdiplus': The specified module could not be found.
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.FunctionWrapper`1.get_Delegate()
   at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdiplusStartup(IntPtr& token, StartupInput& input, StartupOutput& output)
   at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip..cctor()
```

Also I tried to do what was described [here](https://github.com/mono/libgdiplus). But without success.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you only execute the command to install the dependencies? That is not enough, in fact you don't want to do that except as a developer developing the library. Just use the Ubuntu package manager to install the libgdiplus package.

Comment: It reads as if that dll wasn't present in the build artifacts.  Does `dotnet restore` fix this by any chance?  That should've stopped you at compile time, rather than runtime.

Comment: Yeah only did that, how would I install libdigplus ? just sudo apt-get install libdigplus @NineBerry

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libgdiplus`

Comment: @NineBerry No more errors and the image is getting generated, but something wired going on going to update my question.

Comment: @Twenty Write a new question if you have a different (new) problem.

Comment: Okay then I am going to create a new one thanks anyway!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install the gdiplus library using a package manager. For example:

```
sudo apt-get install libgdiplus
```

Comment: @FairyQueen have you tried `brew install mono-libgdiplus`?